# Passing components into components

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 items: `Login`, `Register`, and `AccountForm`. The `AccountForm` should be able to receive the `Login` or the `Register` components as props. I am still a little new to this so having trouble with the execution after having tried a few different things.

`AccountForm`:

```
class AccountForm extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col md="6" className="mx-auto d-flex align-items-center">
                        <Container className="form-container">
                            <Row>
                                <Image src={"/static/frontend/images/digibrain-bubble-bg-black-thin.svg"}
                                       alt="DigiBrain logo"
                                       fluid
                                />
                            </Row>
                            <Row className="mt-4">
                                <Col>
                                    <Container>
                                        { this.props.form } // this is where I would like to pass the forms into.
                                    </Container>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </Container>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

`Login`:

```
class Login extends Component {
    state = {
        username: "",
        password: "",
    }

    static propTypes = {
        login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
    }

    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.login(this.state.username, this.state.password)
    }

    onChange = e => this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });

    render() {
        if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
            return <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>;
        }
        const {username, password} = this.state;

        return (
            <>
                <FormGroup>
                    <h3 className="form-header">Sign In</h3>
                </FormGroup>
                <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            name="username"
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            value={username}
                        />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            className="form-control"
                            name="password"
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            value={password}
                        />
                        <Container className="mb-2">
                            <p className="text-right">
                                <small>
                                    <Link to="/register">Forgot Password?</Link>
                                </small>
                            </p>
                        </Container>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Button
                            type="submit"
                            className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
                            <i className="fas fa-sign-in-alt p-1"/>
                            Sign In
                        </Button>
                        <p className="text-center text-muted">
                            <small>
                                By signing in you agree to our <Link to="/terms-of-service">Terms
                                of
                                Service</Link> and <Link to="/privacy-policy">Privacy
                                Policy</Link>
                            </small>
                        </p>
                        <p className="text-center text-muted">
                            Need an account? <Link to="/register">Sign Up</Link>
                        </p>
                    </FormGroup>
                </Form>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

.. and `Register` is a similar form to `Login` so no need to post it...

My routes look as such:

```
<Route exact path='/register/' component={Register}/>
<Route exact path='/login/' component={Login}/>
```

How can I wrap the `AccountForm` around the `Login` and `Register` components?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `arrow function` to create a dynamic component and send any parameter you want by using the `render` prop.

```
<Route exact path='/register/' render={() => <AccountForm form={Register} />}/>
<Route exact path='/login/' render={() => <AccountForm form={Login} />}/>
```

This time you will be switching from `component` to `render`. The render, as the name implies, can receive a function to render your new component inline. This allows much more flexibility when determining the final component for this route.

You can read more about `Route` and its `render` prop here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func

Comment: Hmm.. this feels like I would be pulling the code towards the top-level, which doesn't feel right; though I could easily be wrong. Is there another way to keep it all within the lower-level modules? Also, I get this error `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, compare, WrappedComponent}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: @DavidAlford This is actually my mistake. This time you need to use `render` instead of `component`. For this case it is pretty much the same thing as component, but allows for inline-rendering. I edited my answer to fix it. I don't think this isn't right, because the `render` was made pretty much for this scenario. You can read more about it here https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func

Comment: I am still getting the same error but not too concerned about the error - just about learning.. instead of handling the render in the `<Route`s, am I able to render the `<AccountForm>` inside the `Login`? I guess I would have to wrap it in a new component called `LoginWrappedAccountForm` or similar?

Comment: @DavidAlford you can do that. Just do `<AccountForm> <Login/> </AccountForm>` and inside the AccountForm's render method you grab the `children` with `const { children } = this.props` and render the children anywhere you want.

Answer (score 1):

We can create HOC - AccountForm and apply it to 'Login' and 'Register' components

For ready reference- https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: I very much like the idea of this and have tried it but am having trouble with the execution. Would you mind giving a code snippet?

Comment: Prepared a stackblitz based on dummy components- https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-starter-yrpipm

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers where helpful, I found a simpler solution which allowed me to keep the code execution at a lower-level. I had to pass the form as children, as I was originally trying to do:

`AccountForm`:

```
class AccountForm extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col md="6" className="mx-auto d-flex align-items-center">
                        <Container className="form-container">
                            <Row>
                                <Image src={"/static/frontend/images/digibrain-bubble-bg-black-thin.svg"}
                                       alt="DigiBrain logo"
                                       fluid
                                />
                            </Row>
                            <Row className="mt-4">
                                <Col>
                                    <Container>
                                        { this.props.children }
                                    </Container>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </Container>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Then I had to wrap the `Login` component in the `<AccountForm>` tags:

```
class Login extends Component {
    state = {
        username: "",
        password: "",
    }

    static propTypes = {
        login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
    }

    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.login(this.state.username, this.state.password)
    }

    onChange = e => this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });

    render() {
        if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
            return <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>;
        }
        const {username, password} = this.state;

        return (
            <AccountForm>
                <FormGroup>
                    <h3 className="form-header">Sign In</h3>
                </FormGroup>
                <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            name="username"
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            value={username}
                        />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            className="form-control"
                            name="password"
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            value={password}
                        />
                        <Container className="mb-2">
                            <p className="text-right">
                                <small>
                                    <Link to="/register">Forgot Password?</Link>
                                </small>
                            </p>
                        </Container>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Button
                            type="submit"
                            className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
                            <i className="fas fa-sign-in-alt p-1"/>
                            Sign In
                        </Button>
                        <p className="text-center text-muted">
                            <small>
                                By signing in you agree to our <Link to="/terms-of-service">Terms
                                of
                                Service</Link> and <Link to="/privacy-policy">Privacy
                                Policy</Link>
                            </small>
                        </p>
                        <p className="text-center text-muted">
                            Need an account? <Link to="/register">Sign Up</Link>
                        </p>
                    </FormGroup>
                </Form>
            </AccountForm>
        );
    }
}
```

This allowed me to keep the `Route` the same while making the `AccountForm` reusable:

```
<Route exact path='/login/' component={Login}/>
```